# Boto3 EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to endpoint (that was previously working fine)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, mechanicalturk

I upgraded to `boto3` a few months ago. These operations always used to work properly. To my knowledge nothing changed, but recently this error has been occurring when I try to reach the `aws` servers.

```
client = boto3.client(
        'mturk',
        aws_access_key_id = key,
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
        endpoint_url= r"https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/")

client.get_hit(HITId=hit.id)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:
"https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

This now happens when posting hits, checking my balance, etc. All these operations were originally working as intended.

My `awscli` is configured to

```
[default]
region=us-east-1
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using an `endpoint_url`?

Comment: **Side-note:** It is not good practice to put AWS credentials within your source code. If you are running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance, then assign an IAM Role to the instance. If you are running on your own computer, use the `aws configure` command from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to store the credentials in a file. You can then remove credentials from your code since the SDK will automatically find them.

Comment: I'm using the `endpoint_url` to quickly be able to switch from the sandbox to the regular version. In reality the endpoints and keys are configured within a general settings file and this allows me to switch around between a number of accounts easily. It's mostly legacy from before `awscli` was around.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me like this:

```py
client = boto3.client('mturk',region_name='us-east-1')
```

Comment: I found out my issues are apparently time related. The same command that works now, might no longer work in a few hours. This is making me think it might be related to (company controlled) fire wall, which changed recently. This works now, but I am almost certain I've tried this earlier. I'll report back.

Comment: I ran into this error, and the key to fixing it was specifying the `region_name`, which my local setup wasn't doing.

Comment: @ultradian Why is this necessary?

Comment: @jtlz2, actually looking at it more closely, it should work if the Region is properly specified in the .aws/config file. Mine had gotten scrambled, and specifying it guaranteed that it was correctly defined.